# inserting in table before declaring cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Can I use the insert statement with values coming from a select statement on another table in `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`?

Like :

```
execute immediate('insert into table values(select rowid from table where column='NEW')');
```

if there is no possibility of this can I put an insert statement before the declaration of a cursor in a procedure.

thanks a lot.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: use backslash... maybe column=\'NEW\'

Comment: "if there is no possibility of this can I put an insert statement before the declaration of a cursor in a procedure." -> do you want to insert a record into a table before you go through a cursor based on that table?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can but you'd need to sort out your syntax and quotes:

```
execute immediate('insert into table (column_name) select rowid from table where column=''NEW''');
```

**EDIT:**

Better still, use a bind variable instead of the hard coded reference to the column name.

Comment: thanks a lot everyone.. Could not type the correct syntax as was using phone. Thanks

Comment: Execute immediate needs no `(` brackets

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, you're right (and I noticed I missed the closing bracket too), the're not NEEDED but I usually do include them as a visual separator and to contain the statement being executed.

Answer (score 0):

What results did you get when you tested it?

Your syntax is a little off, but, as you can see below, it's definitely doable.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE emp2 AS SELECT * FROM emp WHERE 1 = 0;

Table created.

SQL> BEGIN
  2      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO emp2 (empno, ename, job) SELECT e.empno, e.ename, e.job FROM emp e WHERE e.deptno = 10';
  3  END;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT * FROM emp2;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE                    SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- -------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT
      7934 MILLER     CLERK

SQL>
```